# pushviewcontroller iPhone sdk - changing views UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I have a uitabbar application, and I would like to hide the UITabbar whenever a viewcontroller slides in (it is a tableview so whenever a row is tapped).

I would like the tab bar to hide whenever a viewcontroller is pushed and would like the entire screen to be covered with this new view like in iPod application of iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `UIViewController` `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` proprety to YES before you push the viewcontroller.

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```